# Resource Not Found Exception in pyglet

Tags: pyglet

I'm using Python 2.6.6 and pyglet 1.1.4. In my "Erosion" folder, I have "Erosion.py" and a folder named "Images." Inside images, there are .png images. One image is named "Guard.png."

In "Erosion.py" there is a segment that goes like so:

```
pyglet.resource.path = ['Images']
pyglet.resource.reindex()
self.image = pyglet.resource.image('%s%s' % (character, '.png'))
```

When I run this, I am given

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 394, in file raise ResourceNotFoundException(name)
ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "Guard.png" was not found on the path.  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation.
```

I have tried changing the path to ['./Images'] and ['../Images']. I've also tried removing the path and the reindex call and putting Erosion.py and Guard.png in the same folder.

Answer (score 5):

This is what i do to be able to load resources:

```
pyglet.resource.path = ['C:\\Users\\myname\\Downloads\\temp']
pyglet.resource.reindex()

pic = pyglet.resource.image('1.jpg')

texture = pic.get_texture()
gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_NEAREST)

texture.width = 960
texture.height = 720

texture.blit(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: That is, if you really need the resource handler for it.
I use it because it gives me some more additional parameters to work with easy and fast though the GL library.

Comment: This is terrible. When I call "reindex()" my computer seems to index just about EVERYTHING, and takes minutes.

Comment: @BerryTsakala It's designed to index everything in the folders below the patch you gave it. So don't place your script in `\Downloads\` and index from there, instead use a specific folder for your project.

Comment: i just want to play a single file; it shouldn't matter where. Anyway I had so much troubles using it in windows (e.g. with avbin), that I gave up on pyglet completely, and moved to use other modules.

Answer (score 2):

try [this](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/image_viewer.html)

```
pyglet.image.load('path/to/image.png')
```

Comment: http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/playing_sounds_and_music.html
more about loading resources

Answer (score 2):

If the relative path is not working you can try with the absolute path using the os module.

```
import pyglet
import os

working_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
pyglet.resource.path = [os.path.join(working_dir,'Images')]
pyglet.resource.reindex()

image = pyglet.resource.image('character.png'))
```

It's better to use the os.path.join method instead of writing it as a string for a better cross-platform support.

Comment: are you assuming the 'character.png' is in working_dir + "/Images/"

Answer (score 0):

I get a problem like this using pyglet and pyscripter.(the text editor) In order for the file to be found I have to restart the editor before running the program.

This might be a problem with pyscripter however.

Comment: if pyglet doesn't allow specifying full pathname directly, it's a problem in pyglet.

Comment: you probably had to restart the resources file list.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth looking into: http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/resources.html

You should include all the directories into:

```
 pyglet.resource.path = [...]
```

Then pass the ONLY the file name when you call:

```
pyglet.resource.image("ball_color.jpeg")
```

Try:

```
import os
import pyglet

working_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'images')
sound_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'sound')

print working_dir
print "Images are in: " + image_dir
print "Sounds are in: " + sound_dir

pyglet.resource.path = [working_dir, image_dir, sound_dir]
pyglet.resource.reindex()

try:
    window = pyglet.window.Window()
    image = pyglet.resource.image("ball_color.jpeg")

    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        image.blit(0, 0)

    pyglet.app.run()

finally:
    window.close()
```

The use of `try` and `finally` are not necessary, but they are recommended. You might end up with a lot of open windows and pyglet back processes if you don't close the window when there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

pyglet 1.4.4 format: HUD_img = pyglet.resource.image('ui\ui_gray_block_filled.png')

pyglet 1.4.8 format: HUD_img = pyglet.resource.image('ui/ui_gray_block_filled.png')

I was using pyglet 1.4.4 and was able to use this the first format.
After upgrading to pyglet 1.4.8 I had the error: pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "your_resource_path" was not found on the path.

Switching to the 2nd format with forward slashes solved this issue for me. Not sure why this change was made...I'm sure there was a good reason for it.