# Python Cocos2d can't find resource image after resizing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, cocos2d-python

I'm trying to resize an image in Python and then load a cocos2d sprite with the resized image. However, trying to initialize a cocos2d sprite results in an error that the resource can't be found. Example code to reproduce the problem:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import cocos
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("in.jpg")
im.thumbnail((600, 900))
im.save("out.jpg", "JPEG")
im.close()

file = Path("out.jpg")
if file.is_file():
    print("File exists")

sprite = cocos.sprite.Sprite("out.jpg")
```

This results in the error
`pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "out.jpg" was not found on the path.  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation.`

However, the output is:

```
File exists
```

Running it a second time doesn't give errors, since `out.jpg` has been created in the previous run. Deleting `out.jpg` and running it again produces the error.

Adding an `im.close()` didn't solve the problem.

The OS is Windows 10 with Python version 3.6.4.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in `pyglet.resource.image(image)`, which loads the image in the Cocos framework

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the method used in pyglet to load a resource. I had to reindex the images. The files in the images directory where dynamically added and pyglet creates an index of existing images. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16438410/6350693 for the answer.